# emacs: Symbol's value as variable is void: ruby-insert-encoding-magic-comment

Tags: ruby, emacs

I am trying to add ruby-mode to my emacs 
so i created .emacs file and copy the following code into it:

; directory where ruby-emacs.el is located
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0/misc/")

; loads ruby mode when a .rb file is opened.
(autoload 'ruby-mode "ruby-mode" "Major mode for editing ruby scripts." t)

(setq auto-mode-alist  (cons '(".rb$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))

then when i open .rb file, it looks pretty good with color code and
everything, except when i try to save the file, it gives me:

**Symbol's value as variable is void: ruby-insert-encoding-magic-comment**

how can I solve this. i don't know Lisp (took course, but totally forgot:)

my emacs version is: 22.1.1
machine is macbook os x 10.10

thanks.

Comment: In modern Emacs versions, Ruby mode is preinstalled. You can download one from "www.emacsforosx.com".

Comment: Yes, 22.1.1 is very old (2007). Upgrading is recommended.

Comment: Aside from upgrading, i.e., if you stay with Emacs 22, find out where variable `ruby-insert-encoding-magic-comment` is defined (e.g. `grep` for it). And then make sure that file gets loaded also, whenever the code that uses that variable is loaded. (This is a general thing.)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in my Mac and I do not have any idea about lisp either. However I have found a "workaround" by editing the ruby-mode.el file and changed

THIS:

```
((looking-at "\\s *#.*coding\\s *[:=]"))
(t (when ruby-insert-encoding-magic-comment
     (insert "# -*- coding: " coding-system " -*-\n"))))))))
```

INTO THIS:

```
((looking-at "\\s *#.*coding\\s *[:=]"))
   ;(t (when ruby-insert-encoding-magic-comment (insert "# -*- coding: " coding-system " -*-\n")))                              
)))))
```

...and it worked.

I know this does not solve the problem itself, but it's a workaround to avoid the error and keep using emacs :-)